# Running a Kivy screen inside a Pyqt app ,

Tags: python-2.7, kivy

I am trying to make a simple maths quiz game that shows Numbers and when I press space it shows the result , the Application launch with a QTdyalog GUI first and after I finish configuring the gameplay a Kivy screen should show up and the game starts until the user press escape it gets back to the config GUI
here is the Programm skeleton

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, uic
qtCreatorFile = "ConfigForm.ui" # Enter file here.
Ui_MainWindow, QtBaseClass = uic.loadUiType(qtCreatorFile)


class Playy(App): #the Kivy app



    def build(self):

        l = Label(text='Hello world')
        return l



class Conf(QtGui.QDialog, Ui_MainWindow): #the COnfiguration Gui
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        Ui_MainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.buttonBox.accepted.connect(self.oky)
        self.buttonBox.rejected.connect(self.notok)
    def oky(self):
        print "OK OK OK OK" #creating a Kivy app instance and running it 
        ins = Playy()
        ins.run()

    def notok(self):
        print "cancel cancel"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Conf()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I am only having Issue with making functions inside the Kivy app class and passing arguments Into them and also handling Objects properties such as label text this is my first Kivy experiment tell me what do you think

Comment: I don't see error log. But anyway, Kivy isn't a casual package, it's a framework with its own window, therefore I doubt it'll be possible to cross Qt and Kivy in some kind of reasonable way without `subprocess` calling `python <qt app>` and from the `<qt app>` calling `python <kivy app>` after the stuff is done. The same reasoning applies for wxWidgets, tkinter or other gui stuff.